# connect mongodb to nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have mongodb server and nodejs. So I need to connect mongodb to nodejs with IP that mongodb sever provides *(also I have login and password if that makes any difference)*. So that means database is not on local machine.

The idea is simple, I have CLIENT connected to NODEJS through **socket** and nodejs have to make request to MONGODB, get the result and send data back to client.

How exaclty should I connect mongodb in this case and also, do I need to make a connection for every socket opened?

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: aahh, sorry, will update in a sec.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking still. What sockets are opened? You only need one connection to MongoDB from Node -- it will create a pool of connections (# is configurable) automatically. http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/

Comment: I didn't know that would need only 1 connection, so TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the node.js receieve the massage from the client you should make and pass the request to mongodb driver.

you can set the address and port into the mongodb driver as follows:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://user:pass@remotehost:port/DatabaseName", function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('yourcollection');

    var docs = [{mykey:1}, {mykey:2}, {mykey:3}];

    collection.insert(docs, {w:1}, function(err, result) {});

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) to connect to the MongoDB server. The [Quick Start](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) guide shows you how.

To create a socket server that listens for TCP socket connections, you can use [net.createServer()](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener). The linked documentation also has some examples of how to use it.

Comment: This is good as alternative. But I need something more native. TY.